# sorting a file with filters in unix

Tags: sorting, unix, filtering

I have a file in unix which have devices name like

```
dhcpd[16451]:
dhcpd[16451]:
dhcpd[16451]:
dhcpd[16451]:
dhcpd[16451]:
10.254.25.23:
it1bacfw002:
it1bacfw002:
DEVICE-A:
DEVICE-B:
it1bacfw002:
it1bacfw002:
```

I want to sort this file in new file which contains only "." (dot) OR "-" (hyphen).

i.e.

```
10.254.25.23
DEVICE-A
DEVICE-B
```

what shout be the code for this?

Comment: Use `grep` to match the lines you want, and then pipe that to `sort` to sort it. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` and `sort`.

```
grep '[.-]' "${file}" | sort
```

This works because `-` does not create a range if it is the first or last character in a *bracket expression*, and because `.`, like most meta-characters, lose its special meaning in a *bracket expression*.

Comment: Isn't that `.` going to match any character? Is that hyphen going to create a range? Inquiring minds want to know :-)

Comment: According to POSIX, it should work. At least, it works in all the `grep` implementation I tested, ie. `grep (GNU grep) 2.10` and `grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD`.